# How can I fix this "relpath" error

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to use node wrangler for image textures and when I tried to use it I got this error. I have the textures on my main drive and the save file of the project on a different file if that helps explain anything. How can I fix this error?

I tried moving everything to the same drive and that didn't fix it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using relative paths but the files are in different drives. Move all the files to a common directory, where the project file is, or use absolute paths, so that the files are in a fixed location

Comment: That fixed it! Just had to click off relative paths so it was unchecked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using relative paths but the files are in different drives and not in the folder where the project file is. Move all the files to a common directory, along with the project file, or disable relative paths, so that the files are in a fixed location.

From the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/relative_paths.html):

> ## Relative Paths
>
> Many blend-files reference external images or other linked blend-files. A path tells Blender where to look for these files. If the external files are moved, the blend-file that references them will not look right.
> When you specify one of these external files, the default option is to make the path relative. Blender stores a partial path evaluated relative to the directory location of the referencing blend-file. This choice helps when you need to reorganize folders or move your files.
> With a relative path, you can move the blend-file to a new location provided the externally linked files are moved along with it. For example, you could send someone a folder that contains a blend-file and a sub-folder of external images that it references.
> When relative paths are supported, the File Browser provides a Relative Path checkbox, when entering the path into a text field, use a double slash prefix (//) to make it so.